# How can I get Apache Lucene demo web application working in Windows 10?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to follow the Apache Lucene link, https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/demo3.html to build up a demo web application under Windows 10. I have installed the Tomcat web server and successfully got it running. However, when I ran the following command line in CMD:

java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML -create -index {index-dir} ..

It always showed the error: "could not find or load main class org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML".

My Java CLASSPATH has been configured, and I was able to run IndexFiles under Windows 10:

java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs C:/rootpath/chidpath/src

It is very strange as my IndexFiles can be run under Windows 10 without error. Why can IndexHTML  not  be run with the same CLASSPATH setting? Does anyone know how to run an Apache Lucene web application in Windows 10 environment?

Comment: Lucene 2.9.4 was released [over 10 years ago](https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/2.9.4/). It looks as if the demo you want to use requires the Servlet API v2.4 - which, in turn, requires [Tomcat 5.5](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). This is (relatively speaking) all ancient history, and I would not even attempt to use any of it, today.